# Apache Mod Rewrite Rule Interfering with others

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have rules like the following:

```
Redirect 301 /example/test/54 http://newdomain.com.au?ref=hello54
Redirect 301 /example/test/15 http://newdomain.com.au?ref=hello15
```

And then I have another rule:

```
Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com.au?ref=test
```

Anything that isn't captured by the first rules is then captured by the last one.
The problem is say if I do:

`http://olddomain.com/qwerty` it redirects to `http://newdomain.com.au/qwerty`

I need it to just redirect to `http://newdomain.com.au/` (and not append qwerty)

Answer (score 0):

Use `RedirectMatch` for finer control with regex support:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example/test/54/?$ http://newdomain.com.au?ref=hello54
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example/test/15/?$ http://newdomain.com.au?ref=hello15
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ http://newdomain.com.au?ref=test
```